# Why is this combination of constraints ambiguous?

Tags: ios, autolayout

XCode 7

Do you know why this is being considered ambiguous?
I defined that I wanted it centered horizontally and vertically... nothing should be questionable there... then I defined that I wanted it 650 points or larger in horizontal and vertical... so why the ambiguity?

[image: Ambiguous]

** EDIT ** 
I'm following up with some more images based on a comment below.
Notice that ambiguity appears to be resolved, yet I get no output on the screen which should be filled edge to edge with a map view.

[image: Pinned1]

[image: Pinned2]

Comment: Would centered and 700 points wide satisfy your constraints? Would centered and 800 points wide also satisfy your constraints? Yes and yes. Since there are multiple (and, in fact, infinitely many) solutions, it is ambiguous.

Comment: @KenThomases - I see your point Ken, but isn't the whole concept of dynamic interfaces to avoid giving a fixed size where possible?  By saying I want 'no smaller than 650' then in a sense I have given a strict condition for it's size, so I'm still confused how you could allow a control some flexibility in it's sizing WITHOUT introducing ambiguity in the process.

Comment: You don't often specify fixed sizes, but you do need to specify sufficient constraints for the auto layout system to determine a size for your view. There are inputs to the auto layout system that are dynamic but come from outside it. One obvious example is the size of the window. Another is intrinsic size for, say, the text in a label given a certain font. Everything else would be relative, directly or indirectly, to those inputs.

Comment: To think about it another way: would you really be equally satisfied with any layout the system picked so long as the map view is centered and at least 650 points wide and tall? You don't care if there's a lot or a little space all around it? You don't care if it's square or not? You don't care if those things change from run to run or even moment to moment as the user interacts with your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose an inequality constraint of  greater than or equal to.  Since the size could change, (be greater than 650 height or width) it is considered ambiguous.  If you set it equal to 650, it should no longer be considered ambiguous.

Comment: Well, i'm finding myself in a weird predicament with this auto layout stuff because when I tie all sides to the superview instead of or in addition to the 650 constraint, my view either disappears entirely or wanders off part of the screen.  I don't know if the fact that I'm using an ancient 3rd party control (ESRI's ArcGis Map View) would have anything to do with it, but for the life of me I cannot get this map control to fix itself to all four edges of it's superview.

Comment: You can try setting the frame of the control via code at runtime? You can also not set alignment constraints and set distance to superview to 0 in all directions, effectively making it match the size of its superview. That will at least remove ambiguity and make certain that your control is visible.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but in that particular scenario, I wind up with no output at all.  I should have a view filled edge to edge with a map, but nothing.

Comment: In that case it does sound like an unrelated issue. You can confirm by printing your objects frame in the debugger